# accessing XHR within google sheets

Tags: import, google-sheets

I've been using import functions a lot in my sports modeling, but I've never been able to figure out how to get past the issue of pulling information that is dynamically imported from another source.

For example, i'm trying to use importxml to pull the money line values in this link here: https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/nfl-football/money-line/

I can get the information in the left columns up until "PINNACLE", and after research i now understand I can't get the rest of the information because it's not static on the page and I need to go to the source... how do I find the source of this information so I can pull it from there?

I tried inspecting the page, clicking on "network", clicking on "XHR", refreshing the page and previewing the results, but nothing seemed to match.

Am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

The page uses websockets to download the data, so I don't think you could simulate it in *Google spreadsheets* using formulas (maybe it could be possible in a script). However in this particular case there is a 'classic view' variant of the page which includes all the data in its source:

https://classic.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/nfl-football/money-line/